# php if and isset and if variable is not set and doesnt exist

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

Possibly a strange one that I hope can be done in one line.

I have to have an IF statement that will checks two things.

- The first checks if the variable $loggedInfo['status'] is set and is equal to "client".
- The second checks that the variable $loggedInfo['address1'] is set and is blank.

The reason being that when the first variable equals staff then the 'address1' variable doesn't exist.

I did have the following but when I log in as staff it still checks for the address1

```
if((isset($loggedInfo['status'])=="client")&&(!$loggedInfo['address1'])){
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: Are you want to suppress the error of access `address1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isset returs true or false. you have to do separate check for the actual value

```
if(
 isset($loggedInfo['status']) && $loggedInfo['status']=="client" &&
 isset($loggedInfo['address1']) && trim($loggedInfo['address1']) != ''
)
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you just can't compare the return value of `isset()` with the string `"client"`, because it will never equal that. To quote http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php its return values are "`TRUE` if var exists and has value other than `NULL`, `FALSE` otherwise".

First check if it is set

```
if ((isset($loggedInfo['status']) === true) && ($loggedInfo['status'] === "client") && (empty($loggedInfo['address1']) === true)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Key take away from this should be to look up return values for every function you use, like `empty()`, in the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php. This will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((isset($loggedInfo['status']) && $loggedInfo['status']=="client") &&(empty($loggedInfo['address1'])){
  //Do something
}
```

`isset()` returns TRUE if the given variable is defined in the current scope with a non-null value.

`empty()` returns TRUE if the given variable is not defined in the current scope, or if it is defined with a value that is considered "empty". These values are:

```
NULL    // NULL value
0       // Integer/float zero
''      // Empty string
'0'     // String '0'
FALSE   // Boolean FALSE
array() // empty array
```

Depending PHP version, an object with no properties may also be considered empty.